# Invalid address when sending mail via Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to send mail via Django, but have an error: `(501, b'5.1.7 Invalid address', '"emea\\\\sss1ss1"')`
My `EMAIL_HOST_USER = r'emea\xss1ss1'`. As you can see my user consist `\x` so I am using `r''`. How to fix it, the real EMAIL_settings are correct.

my view.py

```
def home(request):
    subject  = 'Test mailing'
    message = 'Hello world!!!'
    email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    recipient_list = ['smth@smth.com']
    send_mail(subject,message,email_from,recipient_list)

    return HttpResponse('Test mailing')
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `r'emea\xss1ss1'` isn't an email address, so why are you trying to set your `email_from` to that value?

Comment: Yep, i've forgot to add corporate domain

Comment: But now I have: (550, b'5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if you want to send an email using Django, first you have to set some variables in `settings.py`.

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.zoho.com'  # for zoho mail service. use smtp.gmail.com for Gmail.
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'something@something.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'something'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = f'Your Name {EMAIL_HOST_USER}'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

then import `send_mail` function and settings:
`from django.core.mail import send_mail`
`from your_project import settings`

```
send_mail(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [user_email, ],)
```

Comment: I have all variables in my settings, but still have the same problem. Maybe it's somehow related to the fact that the host is corporate, and he doesn't let me pass? I know, that another PHP application has the same variables and works correct.

Comment: do you have the DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL and SERVER_EMAIL in your settings.py also?